# Global import and use of mixins file in Angular

Tags: angular, sass, mixins, css-variables

is there a way to create global mixins.scss file in src/assets/style/mixins.scss and be able to use it in every component style sheet without importing it all the time?
For the moment I managed to set up global CSS variable file that i decorated with :root

```
   colors.scss
   root: {
   --primary-white: #FFFFF 
   }
   
   mixins.scss
   root: {
   @mixin my-mixin: linear-gradient(#07347C, #1767AD) 
   }
```

then I can use it in my component file directly without importing it because I have already imported this file in my global stylesheet styles.scss.

```
  // styles.scss
  
  @import 'src/assets/styles/colors.scss
  @import 'src/assets/styles/mixins.scss

  
 // componentStyle.scss 
  
 button {
 @include my-mixin -- this doesn't work
 }
  
 .toolbar {
    background-color: var(--primary-white) -- this works
  }
```

I then created mixins file on the same principle but if I import it in my global scss file I still need to import it in my component scss file.

Is there a way to create global mixins file just like I did with CSS variables and use it everywhere in my application without having to import it every time.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No. Each `SCSS` file need to import the `mixins.scss` (name is up to you) which includes the specific scss.

If you have multiple files, you can create one `all-mixins.scss` which imports all other scss files and then you need only to import this own `all-mixins-scss` in your components. But the `@import` is needed.

#### Workarounds

You can write a build script. Example:

```
// add-imports.js
const glob = require("glob");
const fs = require("fs");

const files = glob.sync("./src/app/**/*.scss");
const importStatement = '@import "path/to/your/mixins";\n';

files.forEach(file => {
  const content = fs.readFileSync(file, "utf8");
  if (!content.startsWith(importStatement)) {
    fs.writeFileSync(file, importStatement + content, "utf8");
  }
});
```

Run this script before you start ng serve - it will be add the import of your file automatically.